# Atmega, avr-gcc, assembly include file from another directory

Tags: avr-gcc

I can't convince avr-gcc on windows to include a *.h file from another directory:

```
>avr-gcc -Wa,-gdwarf2 -x assembler-with-cpp -c -mmcu=atmega256rfr2 halW1.S
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjzoYpN.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjzoYpN.s:6: Error: can't open halGccD.h for reading: No such file or directory
```

The required file is one up level in ../include folder
(this is the BitCloud stack provided by Atmel itself)

I tried as Atmel Studio does to pass include folder:

```
>avr-gcc -Wa,-gdwarf2 -x assembler-with-cpp -c -mmcu=atmega256rfr2 halW1.S -I "..\include"
```

But seems that avr-gcc assembler ignores the -I option. I tried with relative, absolute, even put that path in global PATH.

If I copy required *.h in the same folder where *.S file resides, it's working.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found'it by mistake.
In case anyone needs, -I is not working alone for assembly files. When using avr-gcc as assembler, explicit assembler (-Wa) or linker (-Wl) directives must precede others. Such as:

```
-Wa,-I"..\..\path_to_h"
```

Also pay attention to backslash (not slash)... the old windows problem.
Seems that avr-gcc should parse correctly, but is not.